# Android 10: ACTION_VIEW becomes broken

Tags: android, image, android-intent

One user of my app reports that after upgrading to Android 10 my app on his device stopped displaying an image.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setData(scannedUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have "targetSdkVersion 28" so the new Scoped Storage rules should not be operating.
Still I put "compileSdkVersion 29" and included in the Manifest file:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Still all my user has is an empty screen, while he could see an image before Android 10:
[image: ACTION_VIEW not displaying an image in Android 10]

Comment: The first step is to use a concrete MIME type. It is *your* content that you are offering to other apps, so it is *your* job to provide the actual MIME type for that content. If that does not help, your problem probably comes from whatever `scannedUri` is.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for a fast reply! Evoking of such intent worked even without using the setType() method. scannedUri is actually is a Uri that comes from the call: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() in its listener

Comment: What are you scanning, and where is it located?

Comment: It is an image captured in my app -- I save it to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) via FileOutputStream()

Comment: I am not certain that external storage can be indexed anymore, and I have never tried using a `Uri` returned by `scanFile()` before. You might consider adding `FileProvider` and serving your content using it in the short term. Long-term, you do not have access to `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, and so you will need to do something else.

Comment: The strategy to use Uri from OnScanCompletedListener() has worked all these years flawlessly. MediaScannerConnection was used in order to make sure my written image pops up in the Gallery after the shot (it was important to my users). Anyway do you suggest to go with MediaStorage when saving? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean `MediaStore`, yes, for media, that is one way for saving content. The Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and friends) is another.

Comment: Documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics still is based on using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). Is this outdated now?

Comment: "Is this outdated now?" -- yes, insofar as it is not up to date for Android 10+. If you ignore the `MediaScannerConnection` stuff, your `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will allow `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` to continue working. I am simply uncertain as to how `MediaScannerConnection` works with legacy external storage on Android 10, let alone whether you get a usable `Uri` via the callback. If you switch to using `FileProvider` for your `Uri` source, you can keep the rest of your implementation intact for the short term.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am also facing the above issue when accessing the image from the download directory. I am choosing a gallery to open the intent and facing the issue. Any suggestion to fix the issue

Comment: @RaghulVaikundam: Stop using the download directory, as that seems to be write-only on Android 11. Download the image to some directory that you can read and write (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) and use `FileProvider` to make it available to other apps. Or download the image to a location that the user chooses via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Or download the image into the `MediaStore`. [This 14-post blog series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) covers the second and third options.

Comment: @CommonsWare when I use getExternalFilesDir(), all the files that I downloaded will be deleted upon uninstalling the application. Thereby user has to download again which results in additional usage of mobile data. Besides that, till now the user goes to the Download directory to view the downloaded file. Does it not cause confusion to the user?

Comment: @RaghulVaikundam: If you use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, the user can choose exactly where the user wants you to put the user's image on the user's device or in the user's cloud storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thank you got your point now

Answer (score 2):

i think problem of image extension .jpeg,.jpg or other....

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setData(scannedUri);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and the combination of

```
<external-path name="pics" path="/" /> (used with FileProvider)
```

and

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

solved it for me (I am on SDK version 28).

Just wanted to say thank you for asking this question and providing the READ_URI_PERMISSION flag code, without that I couldn't get it working and I tried like 10 different things!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass [Uri](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ViewContact) like this way, For example

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, imageUri);
```

By default, the system determines the appropriate MIME type required by an intent based on the Uri data that's included.
Setting the MIME type further specifies which kinds of activities should receive the intent.

For instance, If you want to display an image using the ACTION_VIEW `Intent`, you should specify a [MIME](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) type of `image/*`. This stop (someone) from doing something in apps that can "view" other types of data (like a map app) from being triggered by the intent.

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Before Android 10 the code worked even without this call:  intent.setType("image/*");

Comment: If you don't include a Uri in the intent, you should usually use setType() to specify the type of data associated with the intent.

Comment: I do include a Uri -- scannedUri

Comment: It works like this in all Android versions below 10. The issue is either with Android 10 or with it implementation on the particular device